# Airflow XCOM KeyError: 'task_instance'

Tags: python, airflow

I am trying to setup dynamic sequence etl jobs that will use XCOM to get data from the first task that runs. Here is the current code:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime as dt, timedelta as td, date
from airflow.models import BaseOperator
from airflow.operators.sensors import ExternalTaskSensor
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.models import Variable

START_DT = dt.combine(dt.today(), dt.min.time())
END_DT = dt.combine(dt.today(), dt.max.time())
NOW = dt.now()
CURRENT_EXEC = '{{ execution_date }}'
TODAY_MD = dt.today().strftime("%m%d")

def datetime_range(start, end, delta):
    """Generates the date range with time separation"""
    current = start
    if not isinstance(delta, td):
            delta = td(**delta)
    while current < end:
        yield current
        current += delta

default_args = {
        'owner': 'test',
        'depends_on_past': False,
        'start_date': START_DT, 
        'email': ['test@test.com'],
        'email_on_failure': False,
        'email_on_retry': False,
        'queue': 'etl',
        'retries': 1,
        'retry_delay': td(minutes=1),
}

dag_name = 'SEQ_TEST_01'

dag = DAG(dag_id=dag_name, default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=td(minutes=30))

def seq_job(sq_dt, **kwargs):
    for count, dt_in in enumerate(datetime_range(START_DT, END_DT, {'minutes':30}), 1):
        if sq_dt < str(dt_in):
            curr_seq = count, dt_in, dt_in + td(minutes=29, seconds=59)
            sequence = int(curr_seq[0])
            return sequence

pycall = PythonOperator(
    task_id='seq_sensor',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=seq_job,
    op_kwargs={'sq_dt': CURRENT_EXEC},
    dag=dag)

def group(grp, **context):
    sequence = context['task_instance'].xcom_pull(task_ids='seq_sensor')
    grp = '%0.2d' % grp
    database = 'TEST'
    today_date = '{{ ds_nodash }}'
    return BashOperator(
           task_id='ETL_GRP{}_{}_{}'.format(database, sequence, gap),
           bash_command='script.sh {} {} {} {}'.format(today_date, sequence, database, grp), 
           dag=dag)

complete = DummyOperator(
        task_id='All_Sequences_complete',
        dag=dag)

pycall >> group(1) >> complete
pycall >> group(2) >> complete
pycall >> group(3) >> complete
```

Issue is that no matter what i try, i keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/models.py", line 263, in process_file
    m = imp.load_source(mod_name, filepath)
  File "/opt/airflow/incubator-airflow/airflow/dags/new_dag_seq.py", line 66, in <module>
    pycall >> group(1) >> complete
  File "/opt/airflow/incubator-airflow/airflow/dags/new_dag_seq.py", line 56, in group
    sequence = context['task_instance'].xcom_pull(task_ids='seq_sensor')
KeyError: 'task_instance'
```

Not sure if it's something small I am missing, or if I have everything wrong. Still new to airflow and trying to setup our ETL test env to run every 30 minutes with unique sequence number which is generated by `datetime_range` and is based on on execution_date variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it by moving the bash operator to another function and pull the data from python operator via:

```
def bash_out(group, **kwargs):
        sequence = "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='seq_sensor') }}"
        return BashOperator(task_id='ETL_{}_GRP{}'.format(database, group), bash_command='script.sh {} {} {} {}'.format(today_date, database, sequence, group), dag=dag)
```

and setting the dependancies:

```
pycall >> [bash_out('01'), bash_out('02'), bash_out('03')] >> complete
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to use `context['ti']` instead.

Comment: Tried that and still no go :(

Answer (score 2):

Make sure `'provide_context': True` is present in the `default_args`.

Comment: This fixed my case, thanks!